# How to pass a variable from OnCreate to OnListItemClick without declaring it globally in android?

Tags: java, android

The java file: Problem with screens variable ~ I need it in the OnListItemClick method but only after performing the cursor operation and assigning value to tpid. I tried declaring the two methods public didn't help. Also i tried performing the database operation in a separate class but as i am calling this activity from a fragment via a button OnClick, it shows error that cannot cast the new class to ListActivity type even after extending ListActivity to the new class.

```
package utkarsh.project1;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ViewActivity extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("exp",MODE_APPEND,null);
        TableRow tr;
        String q="Select TripID from exp";
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery(q,null);
        String tpid="";
        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            tpid=c.getString(0)+",";
        }
        db.close();
        String screens[]={tpid};
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,screens);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if(screens[position].equals("EXIT"))
        {
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on: " + screens[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String str="utkarsh.project1."+screens[position];
            try
            {
                Class c= Class.forName(str);
                Intent i = new Intent(this,c);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Screen not yet designed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you should not declare globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set **onClickListener** on the listView , instead of extending a **listActivity** simply extend **Activity**, then define a listView object in the **onCreate()**

```
ListView listview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
listview1.setOnItemClickListener(
        new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
               *//Do whatever you want here* 
            }   
        }       
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `getItem(int position)` method of the `Adapter` class to get the selected value. You don't need to access your `screens` variable, since it's already used to back the adapter with data.

Answer (score 0):

you have many errors...

- `ArrayAdapter` basic logic: constructor `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int item_layout, T[] objects)` means: every item in the adapter/listview has the layout `item_layout` and it must and only contain a `TextView` with id `@android:id/text1` which is needed by the inner code of `ArrayAdapter`. you can use complext layout and specify the `TextView` id by other constructors like `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)`, where you can have complext layout but must have a `TextView` with id of `textViewResourceId`. every element of `objects` is bind to corresponding item in the adapter, and the `TextView` in the adapter item is set the text of `objects[index].toString()`.
- the first error of your code is, in `onCreate` you use `screens` to be a plain text string `"id1,id2,id3,..."`, which cannot be understandable by `ArrayAdapter`. based on the logic described above, your `screens` should be a string array like `["id1", "id2", "id3", ...]`.
- because `screens` is bind to the adapter items, you can get the string in `onItemClickListener` by `String screenItemText = ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText();`.
- the major error is that you call database query in main thread... consider move codes from `SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("exp",MODE_APPEND,null);` to `String screens[]=xxxx;` into a background thread. `AsyncTask` is a simple and effective solution.